# Rotated Table Headers HTML and CSS, headers coming out of Headers

Tags: html, css

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th rotate {
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0px;
    /*width: 20px !important;*/
    font-weight: normal;
    
}
.rotate {
             filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083);  /* IE6,IE7 */
         -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.083)"; /* IE8 */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* FF3.5+ */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* IE9+ */
       -o-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Opera 10.5 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Safari 3.1+, Chrome */
          transform: rotate(-90.0deg);  /* Standard */
}
```

```html
<table>
                    <tr>
                          <th  style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                           <div class="rotate"> Header 1</div>
                        </th>    
                        <th  style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                           <div class="rotate"> Big Headerrrrrrrrrrrrr</div>
                        </th>
                       <th style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                           <div class="rotate"> Header 3</div>
                        </th>
                        <th  style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <div class="rotate"> Header 4</div>
                        </th>
                        <th style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <div class="rotate"> Header 5</div>
                        </th>
                        
                    </tr>



                   <tr>
                   <td>
                    Value 1
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 2
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 3
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 4
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 5
                   </td>
                   </tr>
              


                </table>
```

How Can I warp The text in Headers so that they will not come out. I want My Headers Rotate vertically. They can have some height like 150px-300px, if content is big it should break the word. I want this feature because I want to show more columns in A4 prin

Comment: You have several typos, `claas` instead of `class`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode

Comment: @EricPhillips fixed the typos, but still facing issue

Answer (score 0):

The `writing-mode` css propery is all that is needed, see below.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th.rotate {
   writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    
}
```

```html
  <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="rotate" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <div class="rotate"> Header 1</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="rotate" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                           <div class="rotate"> Header 2 Big Headerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</div>
                        </th>
                       <th claas="rotate" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                           <div class="rotate"> Header 3</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="rotate" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <div class="rotate"> Header 4</div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="rotate" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
                          <div class="rotate"> Header 5</div>
                        </th>
                        
                    </tr>



                   <tr>
                   <td>
                    Value 1
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 2
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 3
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 4
                   </td>
                    <td>
                    Value 5
                   </td>
                   </tr>
              


                </table>
```